# scanner is not storing strings past a "space"

Tags: java

Firstly, I'm very beginner, but I like to think I mildly understand things.

I'm trying to write a method that will store the user's input into a string. It works just fine, except if the user puts in a space. Then the string stops storing.

```
public static String READSTRING()   {
        Scanner phrase = new Scanner(System.in);
        String text = phrase.next();
        return text;
    }
```

I think the problem is that phrase.next() stops scanning once it detects a space, but I would like to store that space in the string and continue storing the phrase. Does this require some sort of loop to keep storing it?

Comment: Use `phrase.nextLine()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.nextLine()` instead of `.next()`.

`.nextLine()` will take your input until a newline character has been found (when you press enter, a newline character is added). This essentially allows you to get one line of input.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html), this is what we have:

> A Scanner breaks its input into tokens using a delimiter pattern, which by default matches whitespace.

Either you can use `phrase.nextLine()` as suggested by others, or you can use `Scanner#useDelimiter("\\n")`.

Answer (score 0):

Try `phrase.nextLine();`. If I recall correctly, Scanner automatically uses spaces as delimiters.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
pharse.NextLine();
```

and you got do an array for limited words

```
String Stringname = {"word","word2"};

Random f = new Random(6);
 Stringname = f.nextInt();
```

and you can convert an integer to string

```
int intvalue = 6697;
 String Stringname = integer.ToString(intvalue);
```